# SwitchTo IFrame where XPath contains part of an id

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver

So I have an iframe that pops up when I click a button and I am trying to switch to this iframe. The challenge I am facing is that the ID for the iframe is dynamic depending on the session, so I need to switch to the iframe base on the prefix of the id which is the same regardless.

```
    public void StartMTATransaction(string date)
    {
        Transaction.Clear();
        Transaction.SendKeys("MTA");
        Go.Click();
        ObjectRepository.Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(ObjectRepository.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'dctPopup_dctPopupWindow') and contains(@name,'dctPopup_dctPopupWindow')]")));
        TransactionDate.SendKeys(date);
        ObjectRepository.driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    }
```

When I try to run the code the get the following error on the line 2:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Element I am trying to switch to:

```
<iframe id="dctPopup_dctPopupWindow5D21CAC8BEAC0794DFC40B9D0081D49E" style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent" name="dctPopup_dctPopupWindow5D21CAC8BEAC0794DFC40B9D0081D49E" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `HTML` to switch to the **`IFrame`** you can use the following code block :

```
Go.Click();   
ObjectRepository.Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(ObjectRepository.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'dctPopup_dctPopupWindow')]")));
TransactionDate.SendKeys(date);
```

You can be more granular by coupling the `name` attribute as well :

```
Go.Click();   
ObjectRepository.Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(ObjectRepository.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'dctPopup_dctPopupWindow') and contains(@name,'dctPopup_dctPopupWindow')]")));
TransactionDate.SendKeys(date);
```

But as per the best practices, we should induce **`WebDriverWait`** for the `IFrame` to available for switching as follows :

```
Go.Click();
_wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));
_wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'dctPopup_dctPopupWindow') and contains(@name,'dctPopup_dctPopupWindow')]")));
TransactionDate.SendKeys(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, your xpath need correction.

```
Go.Click();   
ObjectRepository.Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(ObjectRepository.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'dctPopup_')]")));
TransactionDate.SendKeys(date);
```

The correct xpath is `//iframe[contains(@id, 'dctPopup_')]`

Comment: i guess you need to wait till the framework to be loaded. In java, there is a expected condition, frametobeavailabelandswitchtoit. IT will wait until the frame to be loaded and switch to it. I am not sure about in C#

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible using a css selector:

```
iframe[id*='dctPopup']
```

If you want to stick with xpath, try:

```
//iframe[contains(@id, 'dctPopup')]
```

Comment: Using either of them still shows the same error message